# pytube.exceptions.RegexMatchError: __init__: could not find match for ^\w+\W

Tags: python, pytube

So my issue is I run this simple code to attempt to make a pytube stream object...

```py
from pytube import YouTube

yt = YouTube('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQNrG7ag2G4')
stream = yt.streams.filter(file_extension='mp4')
```

And end up with the error in the title.

Full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\test.py", line 4, in <module>
    stream = yt.streams.filter(file_extension='mp4')
  File "C:\Users\logan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 292, in streams       
    return StreamQuery(self.fmt_streams)
  File "C:\Users\logan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 184, in fmt_streams   
    extract.apply_signature(stream_manifest, self.vid_info, self.js)
  File "C:\Users\logan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pytube\extract.py", line 409, in apply_signature
    cipher = Cipher(js=js)
  File "C:\Users\logan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pytube\cipher.py", line 33, in __init__
    raise RegexMatchError(
pytube.exceptions.RegexMatchError: __init__: could not find match for ^\w+\W
```

## Extra data:

python version: 3.8.10
pytube version: 11.0.2

Answer (score 63, accepted):

As juanchosaravia suggested on https://github.com/pytube/pytube/issues/1199, in order to solve the problem, you should go in the cipher.py file and replace the line 30, which is:

```
var_regex = re.compile(r"^\w+\W")
```

With that line:

```
var_regex = re.compile(r"^\$*\w+\W")
```

After that, it worked again.

Comment: How to fix this error in google colab?

Comment: still functioning as a solution as of august 12th 2023 on pytube version 15.0.0

Answer (score 2):

To go cipher.py in the pytube site packages

Change line 30

 **var_regex = re.compile(r"^\w+\W")**

to

**var_regex = re.compile(r"^$*\w+\W")**

"^" means search beginning of the line

".*" means zero or more of any character

"$" means to end of line

Answer (score -1):

In order to solve the problem of " ****init**: could not find match for ^\w+\W** ",
you have to edit a line in *cipher.py* file which is located in

**C:\Users\#####\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pytube\cipher.py**

**replace** the **line 30**, which is:

**var_regex = re.compile(r"^\w+\W")**

with this line :

***var_regex = re.compile(r"^$*\w+\W")**

It will work again.

Comment: what value does this answer add to the question? as far as I can tell, this is the exact same information as is contained in the two other answers, besides the path, which is only valid in very specific cases?

Comment: @Hoodlum Question was specific to PyTube and so do the path mentioned and If it is saving even a second then I think it contains value in it. Everybody can have different perceptions of the things.