# python pytube module: streams not working

Tags: python, pytube

My Code, (I have tried code from other websites too)

```
from pytube import YouTube
yt = YouTube("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oS8lASbvlpI")
myVideoStreams = yt.streams
print(myVideoStreams)
```

Error i got,

```
raise RegexMatchError(
pytube.exceptions.RegexMatchError: __init__: could not find match for ^\w+\W
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pytube.exceptions.RegexMatchError: \_\_init\_\_: could not find match for ^\w+\W](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70776558/pytube-exceptions-regexmatcherror-init-could-not-find-match-for-w-w)

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue when I had pytube with version 10.6.1.

I simply updated it by First Uninstalling it :

`pip uninstall pytube`

Then reinstalling it by:

```
pip install pytube
```

I currently have pytube with version 12.1.2 and issue was resolved for me and hopefully your get resolved too.